# Laravel 5.5 - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am trying to update my data, but i keep getting this error message:
"Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\update.blade.php)".

This is my update.blade.php file

```
@extends ('layout')

@section ('title')

Update page

@stop

@section ('content')

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-12">

        <form action="/todo/save" method="post">

            {{ csrf_field() }}

            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="todo" 
value="{{ $todo->todo }}" placeholder="Type in to create a new todo">

        </form>

    </div>

</div>

<hr>

@foreach ($todo as $todo)

    {{ $todo->todo }} <a href="{{ route('todo.update', ['id' =>$todo->id]) 
}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Update</a> <a href="{{ route('todo.delete', 
['id' =>$todo->id]) }}"class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>

    <hr>

@endforeach 

@stop
```

my controller:

```
public function update($id){

    //dd($id);

    $todo = Todo::find($id);

    return view('update')->with('todo', $todo);  
}
```

and finally my update route:

```
Route::get('/todo/update/{id}', 'TodosController@update')-
>name('todo.update');
```

This is just some basic stuff, but im stuck in here for couple of hours now, and any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: It would help if you add more details about the error, like the line number that causes this error. And I've never tried something like that but I guess `foreach ($todo as $todo)` could cause some problems because both your variables are named `$todo`.

Comment: Iv tried renaming it already but with no luck. Here is the part of the code (my bad for not mentioning it earlier) that causes the error message:

<?php echo e($todo->todo); ?> <a href="<?php echo e(route('todo.update', ['id' =>$todo->id])); ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Update</a> <a href="<?php echo e(route('todo.delete', ['id' =>$todo->id])); ?>"class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
todo.delete, todo.update and id are reported as an error.

Answer (score 1):

Use `findOrFail` method on your controller to throw an Exception if $todo is empty

```
public function update($id){

    $todo = Todo::findOrFail($id);

    return view('update', compact('todo'));  
}
```

The problem is also on your `update.blade.php` file. `foreach $todo as todo`, `$todo` has collection of eloquent model or eloquent model ? I think it's a eloquent model. So a loop doesnt have any sense.

Comment: seems to me that it is some route related issue.

Comment: It just keeps giving me the same annoying error message.

Answer (score 0):

That error would happen if `todo` were FALSE or some other non-object.

You can inspect it with a `var_dump($todo);die();` in the controller.

Comment: I get confirmation of todo being an object.

Comment: As soon as you call `foreach ($todo as $todo)` you are overwriting the object with its first property, as I see you've been told by others. That loop breaks your variable on the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

`find()` will return either `null` or the model that is found. Assuming that the model is found, you're doing a for each on that model (`foreach ($todo...)`), which will iterate over the model's public properties. This is obviously not what you intend to do.

It looks to me like you're trying to loop over a list of your todos and print out edit/delete links. If this is the case, you need to get the list of your todos in your controller, pass it into your view, and fix your `foreach` statement.

Controller:

```
$todos = Todo::get();
// pass to view
```

View:

```
foreach ($todos as $todo)
```